# Unable to find device path for ESP8266

Tags: usb, python

I'm trying to flash MicroPython using esptool onto my ESP8266 chip (using [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821) board) and I'm getting stuck at deploying the firmware (currently following the [MicroPython docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/intro.html)).

When I try to find the dev path, ttyUSB doesnt appear at all

```
tristan@tristan-Laptop:~$ ls /dev/tty.*
ls: cannot access '/dev/tty.*': No such file or directory
tristan@tristan-Laptop:~$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
tristan@tristan-Laptop:~$
```

This is my output when using *lsusb*

```
tristan@tristan-Laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 27c6:609c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5634 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Laptop Camera
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've determined my device is Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge so I tried to run the erase flash command at `/dev/bus/usb/003/014` this was my output

```
tristan@tristan-Laptop:~$ sudo esptool.py --port /dev/bus/usb/003/014 erase_flash
esptool.py v4.1
Serial port /dev/bus/usb/003/014
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 398, in _reconfigure_port
    orig_attr = termios.tcgetattr(self.fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/esptool.py", line 34, in <module>
    esptool._main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/esptool/__init__.py", line 995, in _main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/esptool/__init__.py", line 637, in main
    esp = esp or get_default_connected_device(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/esptool/__init__.py", line 880, in get_default_connected_device
    _esp = detect_chip(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/esptool/cmds.py", line 88, in detect_chip
    detect_port = ESPLoader(port, baud, trace_enabled=trace_enabled)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/esptool/loader.py", line 246, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/serial/__init__.py", line 90, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 332, in open
    self._reconfigure_port(force_update=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 401, in _reconfigure_port
    raise SerialException("Could not configure port: {}".format(msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
sudo apt remove brltty
```

Then restart your PC. It works for me!